# I know my series converges; how do I get a closed-form expression for it?

Tags: summation, closed-form, mathematica

I'm new to Mathematica. I'm trying to find a result in terms of $a$ and $c$ for the following summation with the restrictions declared in the code below:

```
Assuming[a > 0 && -1 < c < 0, Sum[Exp[-a*Sqrt[i + c]]/Sqrt[i + c], {i, 1, ∞}]]
```

Though this is a convergent series, the above yields no result; it gives an output like the following:

$\qquad \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-a\sqrt{c+i}}}{\sqrt{c+i}}}$

Even `Simplify` does not work!

Apart from Mathematica, does anyone have any idea how I can analytically obtain a closed form expression for the above summation?

I will be really grateful if somebody can help with my problem.

Comment: Convergence does not imply that a series will have a closed form expression. For specific values of `a` and `c`, you should be able to use `NSum[]` to evaluate numerically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you very much for your reply. Well, I know that with specific values of a and c, the command NSum will work. I am only wondering if there is another command in Mathematica which could be useful in my case, producing a closed form expression. Anyhow, your reply has revealed to me that there is no such possibility with Mathematica.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks a lot for editing my question, though I was expecting an answer to my problem rather than an edition! I'm sorry, I was not familiar with this environment, I didn't know it's like writing an ISI paper! After all, you are right, every community has a rule and I should have respected yours. Many thanks for taking your time on my question.

Comment: Is there some reason to believe a closed form exists in terms of elementary or special functions?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for your comment. I thought since my series is convergent, there must be a closed form expression in terms of the parameters included. But according to J.M. comment, it seems my belief was wrong. No, at the moment there is no reason to believe a closed form exists. Only for my calculations I need to find such an expression.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but maybe a parametrized estimate will suffice? If so, you could sum to a finite value and use the integral as approximation from there (but I have not actually checked if the integral is a valid approximation). I suggest this because the corresponding integral apparently does have a closed form: `In[1227]:= Integrate[
 Exp[-a*Sqrt[i + c]]/Sqrt[i + c], {i, 1, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, -1 < c < 1}]

Out[1227]= (2 E^(-a Sqrt[1 + c]))/a`

Comment: If your reputation-number is high enough you can edit others' Q's. But the site's moderators review them  and can reject  an edit. And you can always edit your own Q.

Comment: @m_goldberg . I respectfully disagree. It is just a Q on whether a series has a closed form. There are many Q's like it on this site.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks a lot for your reply. You are right, this problem has an "easy to get" Integral but I think it's not a good approximation for the summation. Because in Integration $i$ is a continuous variable whereas in summation it is a discrete integer variable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'm sorry, I forgot to answer your first question; yes, a parametrized estimate is sufficient.